# Beginners guide to Rational Functional Tester

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, rft

I have to study automation of web pages using Rational Functional Tester in 3-4 days. How different is automation in RFT from Automation in Selenium? Also, please suggest some good content available online for testing web applications using RFT.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are able to find the most basic tutorials to get your hands on RFT (I always recommended [the one](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_9.1.0/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.tutorial.doc/topics/a_ft_intro.html) of IBM's Knowledge Center). I find it more beneficial to use some tutorials guiding the way how to use RFT and how to organize your test code—they also show the key functionality of RFT and how to get the most out of it. Some I like particularly are [Create a test framework using Rational Functional Tester](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/test-automation-framework-rational-functional-tester/), [An Object-Oriented framework for IBM Rational Functional Tester](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0124_snow/index.html), and [Effective test automation techniques for Rational Functional Tester](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0619_kelly/).

In my opinion, the biggest difference between Rational Functional Tester and Selenium is RFT's Test Object Map in which the GUI objects for the test cases are managed. Although it is there and I think it is also quite useful, you can go more or less completely without it using the [TestObject.find](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0711_nowacki_nodwell/) method. Another big difference is the Recorder in Rational Functional Tester to record simple GUI tests (but I cannot recommend Capture-Replay Tests). If you use some pattern like Page Objects, you won't have big problems to use either tool.